# Pulling data from AWS instance in csv to Salesforce

Tags: data-loader

Scenario - Files will be kept in .csv format in AWS instance.

Requirement - Need to invoke Dataloader from CLI .

How do I access the data kept in the remote url and update objects in SFDC through Data Loader from CLI.

Comment: you missed two paragraphs in your question -- what you've done already, and what kind of errors did you get during that

Comment: @kurunve - I haven't started off yet . I am a complete newbie in this . Need basic idea on how to startoff .

Comment: @kurunve -Only aware about the Dataloader part . Need to get an idea to fetch .csv file from the remote url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell is your friend bud, and so is Windows Task Scheduler.

1) Write a Powershell script that gets your file (below is a basic example), and drops it in a directory.

```
$source = "http://learnhowtogoogle.com/file.csv"
$destination = "c:\application\data\newdata.csv"

Invoke-WebRequest $source -OutFile $destination
```

2) Write a PowerShell script that then runs Data Loader via the command line. Read the documentation, it requires that you create a process bean among other things, but it is well documented and you should be able to figure it out ;).

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line

3) Use Windows Task Scheduler (or some other tool) to schedule your PowerShell scripts to run consectively at a desired time every day (Ideally when few users are in the system).

BOOM! Automation baby! Manual Data Loads are forever abolished!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Data Loader can directly connect to AWS and pull the files. To use Data Loader, you have to somehow pull the files and then run the Data Loader from CLI.

[Here is an interesting article](http://www.chiragmehta.info/chirag/2010/03/22/salesforce-ftp-integration-data-loader-web-service-http/) describing different options for Salesforce – FTP Integration. I think this is a good starting point.

The options described are:

**I – Data Loader CLI – Windows approach.**

1 - Download Salesforce Data Loader Command Line Interface (Read more at http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line)

2 - Write a Widows Batch file (.bat file)

3 - First command in the batch file will be connect to FTP server (ms-dos command ‘ftp’) and then get the necessary files from ftp server to the local folder.

4 - Second set of commands execute the Data Loader CLI jar and loads step3 retrieved file into Salesforce.

5 - To automate the execution of the batch, we can schedule the bat file execution using scheduled task feature of Windows operating system.

**II – Java Web Service**

1 - Write a Java FTP client, expose it as a Web Service

2 - Consume above WS into your Salesforce Org using Apex “Browse WSDL” functionality

**III – Http Request**

1 - Create a Http Request to the FTP server

2 - Handle the response using either of HttpRequest and HttpResponse Apex Class

3 - Ps: The problem that you can face is the size of the files. Please remember that HTTP Request size are currently limited to 100Kb of data, so larger exports would fail unless a mechanism was created to utilize multi-part transmissions.